# How to include contents in EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am having some trouble with something that (I think) ought to be simple.
My web app is a `Node.js` one with `express` and `ejs`.

I contains code like this (very classical in such a case) in index.js:

```
var app = express();

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Now here is the issue I have.

Among all my .ejs files, some happen to need the same code (written by me). In order to avoid repetition I want to have this code in a separate file and then include it when necessary, but I can't find the proper way to do it. I put the code in a file called Utils.ejs (in the partials folder) then used this:

```
<% include ../partials/Utils.ejs %>
```

but it does not work. I then searched the net and tried a few variations, but found nothing working.

Does any one know how I can do that?

For information about versions, here is what I have in my package.json file:

```
"ejs": "^2.5.7",
"express": "~4.11.x",
"node": ">=4.3"
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your folder structure? like where you pages are placed and where your partials are placed ?

Comment: I am now showing the folder stucture. I chose to place my file along with other included .ejs files. Was that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do Not include the file extension while u import the partials

Remove the `.ejs` from the `<% include ../partials/Utils.ejs %>` and try

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion: removing ".ejs", but it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

remove ".." and ".ejs", also make sure that "/partials/Utils/" is in public folder

```
<% include /partials/Utils %>
```

Comment: Now it is not in public. It is in view like other included files (header.ejs & nav.ejs).

Answer (score 0):

here in this line

`app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');`

make it

`app.set('views', __dirname + '/views/pages/');`

this way it will work fine, you can access all view pages (`views/pages/`) directly, and your partial views (`views/partials/`) are also accessible from the pages folder.

Comment: I tried, it doen't work. I get this error: " Error: Could not find include include file.".

Comment: try removing the line
`app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));`
 I think this might be causing trouble.

Comment: I just tried, it doesn't work. I get the message "myFunc is not defined". myFunc is defined inside Utils.ejs.